# Display Image Through New Parse Config

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, parse-platform, config

So I am using the new Parse Config for my application. The easy part was the installation of the `NSString`, but now I am working on the `ImageView`. Can someone help me figure out how to execute this? 
Here is how I am calling for a `NSString`:

> ```
> [PFConfig getConfigInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFConfig *config, NSError *error) {
>     NSNumber *number = config[@"numberOne"];
>     textLabel.text = [number stringValue];
> }];
> ```

Now I have created an Image called `mainImage` and I need this to set to `mainImageFile` from my Parse server. This is where I got stuck:

```
   [PFConfig getConfigInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFConfig *config, NSError *error) {
        PFFile *pfFileMainImage = config[@"mainImageFile"];
    //
    //
    }];
```

If this helps.. This is how I would set the images from Parse in `tableView`:

> PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];  PFImageView
>   *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];  thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage
>   imageNamed:@"add-photo-placeholder.png"];  thumbnailImageView.file =
>   thumbnail;  [thumbnailImageView loadInBackground];

Thank you!